# Maximum # Simultaneous Downloads with NSURLSession Regardless of Host

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionconfiguration

I know about the `HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost` option on `NSURLSessionConfiguration`... but how many connections can iOS handle irrespective of host?

I assume this depends on some combination of... the # of cores.. the network interface.. and how busy the OS is in general + with downloads for other applications.

Can't find any hints about this.

Regardless I assume it's ridiculous to expect more than 2 or 3 at once..

**Edit**

Assuming the ability to have as many hosts and NSURLSession instances as wanted

Answer (score 1):

You can set more than 1000. As you know, Apples's document doesn't specify upper limit.

To download about 2000 small files in background, I set httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost to 2000, and tested w/ iPhone7+/iOs10.3.1 under WiFi. It worked w/o any issue. Then, I tested download time by changing
httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost, and realized that increasing the number doesn't necessarily buy download time. So, for now, I'm leaving it to default value (=4). I think you need to examine with your apps (number of files, size, etc.).

Comment: ya i'm trying to build a priority based queue system, where i'm always downloading something... but leaving open immediate pathways in case a critical download need arises. And I have the ability to distribute the load over as many hosts as i want really, as i use IPs instead of hostnames.

Comment: haha for some reason I just really don't believe it's going to be in real time downloading 4 different files simultaneously. But I need to do some testing! I was just wondering if someone already knew..